# CPU performance control WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, graph

I need a control in silverlight that shows a CPU performance in real time just like the windows task manager does.

Something like:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by need a control?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The free and awesome [WPF Dynamic Data Display](http://www.codeplex.com/dynamicdatadisplay) library comes with a performance counter sample which does this, and which you can customise to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the information by querying the wmi.

Comment: yes but how do i show it in silver light or what 
data visualizer/control should i use for real time updates. I need to show it in line graph

Comment: What you need then is a *wpf line graph control*. See Oliver's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Currently i'm not really working with WPF, but a [search with google for 'wpf chart control'](http://www.google.com/search?q=wpf+chart+control) gives a lot of promising links.

Comment: I and doing for about week and it does return many of 3rd party charts but i need chart with plots data realtime just as windows task manager does.

Answer (score 1):

WPF toolkit has the a good set of chart control, You can use LineSeries control for this. http://wpf.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=29117

Answer (score 0):

The [Silverlight toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Silverlight%20Toolkit%20Overview%20Part%202&referringTitle=Home) will give you all you need to display such a graph, but you won´t be able to get the data from the client itself in silverlight!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great control for that purpose:
http://blog.rthand.com/post/2012/01/10/Realtime-graph-for-WPF.aspx